# Playlists on Android phone

Tags: android, music, rhythmbox, clementine, playlists

I have a serious problem with the Ubuntu music players. I'm at the point where 
I'm going to switch back to Windows because I can't figure this out 
and nobody seems to be able to help. If anybody knows how to transfer 
playlists from Clementine a microSD for my Android phone, I would 
appreciate it if they told me how to do it. I use Clementine, but I haven't been able to do this with Rhythmbox either.

People seem to think that I want to transfer the individuals files to 
my phone, but that's not the case. I have a playlist for each genre of 
music. For instance, I have a rock music playlist, a dance music 
playlist, an electronic music playlist, etc. I have these playlists on 
my computer in Clementine. I would like to put the playlists that I've 
designed in Clementine on my Android phone. I'm sure some Ubuntu user 
has managed to do this, as this is a simple thing that Apple and 
Windows users do easily all the time.

I have tried copying and pasting .xspf playlists to my microSD card, but the songs 
don't transfer, although the playlist titles do.

I have also copied songs onto my microSD card, but they are not in a 
distinct playlist.

Please help me put playlists on my phone. iTunes does this easily. This has to 
be much easier than it has been for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try synchronizing your playlists between computer and android phone over Ubuntu One.
Check this [link](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-edit-playlists-in-ubuntu-one-music-for-android/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do. I load the songs that I want in my playlist into clementine. I then mount my android phone directory. I then select all the songs in my play list (control-a) and drag and drop them into my desired directory on my sd card. I then save the play list (Control-s) of all the songs that are currently in my play list (I change the extension from xspf to m3u) and save that into the directory I just put the songs.

Sometimes I have to restart the android device to force it to do a search for songs and playlists. Sometimes it finds them when I restart the audio player. I use this on both my Sprint evo 3d and my Vizio tablet.

I used to try and use the connect to device tools on music players but I am too much of a control freak to let the programs do it. In addition, since there is not real standard each time one side or the other changes the tools bites the dust.

hope it helps, john.

Answer (score 0):

Just elaborating on @john answer:

- Install Gsconnect on Ubuntu
- Install KDE connect on Android
- On Ubuntu also install: python-nautilus, gir1.2-nautilus-3.0

After this GS connect should be able to see the Android device connected via USB

- In KDE settings, select your PC ( theoretically multiple devices can be connected ), > plugin settings > File system expose ( enabled ) > Configured storage locations > Add storage location > You should be able to select/create a new folder on the SD card ..say music
- From Gsconnect > Mount
  GS connect ( mount changes to files )...select files and select the 'music' folder here.
- Now you should be able to copy any folder from Ubuntu to this folder
- Use PI music player > Folders > navigate to music folder and select any folder to play music within the folder